# javac.exe not found in JDK 1.8

Tags: java, java-8, javac

I am installed JDK 1.8 in Windows 7x64. But javac.exe not found in /bin folder. How to fix this problem? Anybody resolve it?

Paths set.
[image]

Comment: I advise you to reinstall jdk and then add {java folder}/bin to your PATH environmental variable

Comment: Don't forget to open a new cmd after your path changes ...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko - I you sure you attentively read the post? Reread again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed it installed JDK again. An installer ask you install JRE. Need to decline it and all be fine.

Thanks all.

P.S. Read body post attentively. Always.

Answer (score 0):

`javac` is inside bin folder. You should change `PATH` to reflect that. Make sure the content of `PATH` looks like this:

```
PATH = %JDK_HOME%\bin;... (rest of the value of PATH)
```

Comment: I've read it and you haven't changed anything. I know this works, I've done this in several computers before. If it doesn't work in yours then provide more info to understand what's happening in your environment, otherwise it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: By the way, you should add `%JDK_HOME%\bin` to path, include **bin** folder. If you don't, then you're unable to call `javac` from the cmd.

Comment: I have wrote path has been added. You can see it on screenshot also.

Comment: In the image you have **NEVER** updated PATH. Defining an environment variable doesn't mean that the folders inside there will be automatically added into `PATH`. Since you haven't modified `PATH`, you cannot access to `javac`. Access to environment variables in your Windows installation, check PATH, and edit it accordingly as shown in this post.

Answer (score 0):

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%JDK_HOME%\bin;
```

this should solve your problem. it adds the bin directory to your path variable and makes all exe files excutable without using the fully qualified path.

Comment: please, reread post attentively again. I'm write I'm added path.

Comment: Really? How do you know it? Anyway, you are not inattentive. I'm writing this for fifth time.