# I need help setting up Java

Tags: java

I installed `jre1.8.0_211` (first) and `jdk-12.0.1`.

My Environment Variables:

```
JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1

CLASSPATH
;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;
%JAVA_HOME%\lib\htmlconverter.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\rt.jar;

Path
;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Apparently it's set up correctly, but it still doesn't work.

`javac` in Command Prompt results in:

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Although `java` works correctly.

Can someone help me set up correctly?

Comment: You probably aren't quoting things correctly. Show us how you've set those environment variables.

Comment: If you run `java -version`, does it say Java 8 or Java 12?

Comment: Also you shouldn't need to put any of those things on the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Can you run echo %JAVA_HOME% and see what it returns ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do any of this. I haven't messed around with environment variables after a Java install for 20 years, except for other things like Netbeans and Tomcat.

Comment: If you are not able to find out resolution, try to install NetBeans8.2 , It came with all required things to run java and your environment will be set as well. :)

Comment: possibly helpful or related [Java 1.8.65 javac is missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559379/java-1-8-65-javac-is-missing), [javac.exe not found in JDK 1.8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33943592/javac-exe-not-found-in-jdk-1-8)

Answer (score 0):

[this is the first image ,paste bin directory in new path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwtTQ.png)

[follow my step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAr4q.png)